# WYSIWYG editor not shown other roles

Tags: drupal-7, wysiwyg

i enable WYSIWYG editor in my site its works fine in admin login but i am not able to see this editor in other roles.i enable the access permission for text format for other roles but editor not shown in other roles.

any one helps me to sorts out this issue.

Advance thanks

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same problem that the WYSIWYG editor displays for the admin, however it is hidden for the other roles those have the proper text format.

I couldn't find a patch, however to workaround it just add the permissions **"show format selection for nodes"** to the other roles, and the rich text editor will be displayed for them.

Comment: This is a bug when better formats module meets wysiwyg. Relevant issues for Better Formats http://drupal.org/node/1687956 and Wysiwyg api http://drupal.org/node/934976

Answer (score 0):

The text editor is presented in 3 formats: Filtred html,Full Html and Plain text ,check wich format is assigned to the suitable roles